# Value of column computed from ID on insert in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

I have a table in SQL Server 2012,

```
CREATE TABLE [dev].[File] 
(
    id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    fileUrl VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The value of *fileUrl* however needs to be calculated based on a prefix and the value of the *id* field. i.e

```
fileUrl = <file_directory>/<id>.<file_extension> // id needs to be computed when created
// e.g. http://example.com/<id>.xlsx
```

So using sequelize.js it needs to be something like,

```
const filePath = 'http://example.com'
const fileExtension = '.xlsx'
File.create({
 fileUrl: // What goes here?
})
```

One way to do this is create row with empty fileUrl, then find and update based on id.

Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: If you are not dealing with millions of records, then you can create one more row and make it computed in SQL as fileUrlpath as replace(fileurl,'<id>',id)

Comment: The value of the identity won't be final until the row is inserted, so no, not really. You can at least create a stored procedure that uses `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to do the insert and update in one single transaction, which makes for easier calling and reduces log overhead. You could also consider using a locally generated GUID as your URL identifier instead of the identity of the row, or use a T-SQL `SEQUENCE` instead of an identity, either of which allow you to generate both ID and URL before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an identity as the PK then you have to do as you've described (or as per @maulik kansara's comment) . What we used to do before identity columns were invented  is:

Create a table called e.g. NextValue with one column e.g. NextKey bigint not null. Pseudo code:

```
read nextKey into localvalue

update NextLalue set NextKey = NextKey + 1 where NextKey = localvalue

if row was updated continue else go back to start


use localvalue as [dev].file.id.
```

There are several variations on this, but that's the heart of it.